# if x.shape is not None and len(x.shape) == 1: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'shape'

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I am a beginner in Deep Learning and was building a program that determines the person from its image. But my neural network is showing an error and I have no idea on how to fix it -"

```
model.fit(imgs_array,Y,batch_size = 401, epochs = 2, validation_split = 0.2, sample_weight= None)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 1527, in fit
    x, y, sample_weights = self._standardize_user_data(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 991, in _standardize_user_data
    x, y, sample_weights = self._standardize_weights(x, y, sample_weight,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 1149, in _standardize_weights
    y = training_utils.standardize_input_data(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_utils.py", line 284, in standardize_input_data
    data = [standardize_single_array(x) for x in data]
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_utils.py", line 284, in <listcomp>
    data = [standardize_single_array(x) for x in data]
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_utils.py", line 218, in standardize_single_array
    if x.shape is not None and len(x.shape) == 1:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

'"

My complete code is

```
import os
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import load_img, img_to_array
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from tensorflow.python import keras
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Conv2D, Dropout


folders = os.listdir('lfw/')
folders_a = np.asarray(folders)

X = []
Y = []
for folder in folders:
    files = os.listdir('lfw/'+folder+'/')       # type of files is a list
    image_files.append(files)
    for file in files:
        X.append(file)
        Y.append(folder)

# print(len(Y))     #13233
img_paths = []
for i in range(0,13233):
    img_paths.append('lfw/'+Y[i]+'/'+X[i])      #img_paths is set now

print(len(img_paths))
i =0
imgs = []
for img_path in img_paths:
    img_1 = load_img(img_path, color_mode="grayscale")
    imgs.append(img_to_array(img_1))
    print("executed",i)
    i+=1
    # print(imgs[0].shape)      #(250,250,1)

#Building Neural Network
imgs_array = np.array(imgs)
imgs_array /= 255

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(20, kernel_size = 3, activation = 'relu', input_shape =(250,250,1)))
model.add(Conv2D(20, kernel_size =3, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(5749,activation = 'softmax'))    #the number of people in dataset are 5749

model.compile(loss = keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,optimizer = 'adam', metrics = ['accuracy'])

model.fit(imgs_array,Y,batch_size = 401, epochs = 2, validation_split = 0.2)
```

The keras documentation says

"sample_weight: Optional Numpy array of weights for the training samples, used for weighting the loss function (during training only). You can either pass a flat (1D) Numpy array with the same length as the input samples (1:1 mapping between weights and samples), or in the case of temporal data, you can pass a 2D array with shape `(samples, sequence_length)`, to apply a different weight to every timestep of every sample. In this case you should make sure to specify `sample_weight_mode="temporal"` in compile(). This argument is not supported when x generator, or Sequence instance, instead provide the sample_weights as the third element of x."

But this did not help me. 
What is the cause of the error and how to fix it?

Comment: Sounds like you need to check the values in `imgs_array` to see if it contains array of string instead of array of arrays

Comment: One of those arguments must be a string instead of an ndarray. - what is `Y`? a list of strings?

Comment: I don't know Tensorflow. Does it match the description for the 'Y' parameter? https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Sequential#fit